# Neo4j Cypher: Group nodes by the relation to another node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Having a graph like `post-->category`, how can I get one post per category?

i.e.:

```
Having
    Post A1 --> Category A
    Post A2 --> Category A
    Post B1 --> Category B
    Post B2 --> Category B
    Post B3 --> Category B
    Post C1 --> Category C

I should get Post A2, Post B1, Post C1.
```

I don't mind what post I get for a given category, just to get one for each category.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To pick a post per category by random:

```
MATCH (p:Post)-[:HAS_CATEGORY]->(c:Category)
WITH c, collect(p) as posts
RETURN c, posts[toInt(rand()*length(posts))]
```

We're using the `collect` aggregation function per category and in the return we pick one entry by random.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Coming from SQL, its hard for me to use aggregations only by selecting a field and a function on the data. :)
And I'm sorry I cannot upvote the anwser :(